# How is this prime-related equality obtained?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Could someone please explain how the following equality is obtained?

> Let $p_i$ denote the $i$th prime, and let $r \in \mathbb{N}$. Then
>   $$\prod_{1 \leq i \leq r} \left(1-\frac{1}{p_i}\right) + \prod_{1 \leq i \leq r} \left(1+\frac{1}{p_i}\right) = 2\left(1 + \sum_{s=1}^{\lfloor r/2 \rfloor} \sum_{1 \leq i_2 < i_3 ... <i_{2s} \leq r} \frac{1}{\prod_{j=1}^{2s} p_{i_j}}\right)$$

The context is that I saw this equality in a proof for the inequality $\phi(n) + \sigma(n) \geq 2n$ for all positive integers $n$, where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function and $\sigma$ is the sum-of-divisors function.

I would imagine that there is some inclusion-exclusion that I'm not seeing.

Comment: The terms with an odd amount of primes have opposite parity in the expansion of the two products, so they cancel. Thus, we are left with 2 times the sum of all the terms with even amounts of primes, which is just the sum given in the parentheses.

Comment: @william122 Right, thanks. If you'd like, you can make that an answer which I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simpler than Inclusion-Exclusion. It is simply that $-1$ to an even power is $1$, while $-1$ to an odd power is $-1$:
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{i=1}^r\left(1-\frac1{p_i}\right)+\prod_{i=1}^r\left(1+\frac1{p_i}\right)
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor r/2\rfloor}2\sum_{|A|=2k}\prod_{i\in A}\frac1{p_i}\tag1\\[6pt]
&=2\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor r/2\rfloor}\sum_{|A|=2k}\frac1{\prod\limits_{i\in A}p_i}\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: the products of an odd number of terms in the first product cancel those in the second
$\phantom{(1)\text{:}}$ the products of an even number of terms in the first product add to those in the second
$(2)$: distribute the $2$ and the product of reciprocals is the reciprocal of the product